# How to make my panel move?

Tags: c#, select, panel, move, picturebox

What's the deal, i have an imagePanel (u can look at it as a picturePanel)
called imagePanel1 (i imported it so i don't have to make scroll Bars :))

and i have a treeView on the left side, from witch i can drag a node, and drop it over the imagePanel, where i get a Location of the drop, and on that location i create a normal panel called panel1
And so i do 100 times, so at the end i ll have an imagePanel full of small panels...
Now is the problem, when i click on the imagePanel (where a panel is located)
I want that panel to be selected on MousePress, and moved on mouseMove, and eventualLy deleted on a btnDelete...

Here is the code for the imagePanel:
//***********************************************************************

```
    private void imagePanel1_DragDrop_1(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Type testTip = new TreeNode().GetType();
        YLScsImage.ImagePanel dropPicturePanel = (YLScsImage.ImagePanel)sender; 
        TreeNode movedNode;
        _mouseDownSelectedWindow = Rectangle.Empty;
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(testtype)) 
        {
            movedNode= (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData(testType);
            dropPicturePanel.Tag = movedNode.Tag;

            movedNode.ImageIndex = 1;
            movedNode.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
            movedNode.ForeColor = Color.Gray;


//**************************************
//HERE IS THE CODE FOR THE CREATED PANEL

            Panel panel1 = new Panel();
            Point point1 = this.PointToClient(new Point(e.X - 278, e.Y - 19)); //the imagePanel1 is on the form at the point 278,19

            panel1.AllowDrop = true;
            panel1.Location = point1;
            panel1.BackgroundImage = iltest.Images[0]; //nvm
            panel1.Height = 16;
            panel1.Width = 16;
            imagePanel1.Controls.Add(panel1); //am adding it to the imagePanel1


   //saving the locations of each panel
            string path = @"C:\Users\Cosic\Desktop\ICR\TABELA3_Paneli.txt"; // path to file
            if (!File.Exists(path))
                File.Create(path);
            if (panelBr == 0)
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, new byte[0]); //brise ceo text iz fajla

            TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
            sw.WriteLine(e.X + "; " + e.Y + "; " + panel1.Width + "; " + panel1.Height + ";");
            sw.Close();
   //am done with saving
            panelBr++;//nvm

        }
    }
```

tell me if u need some more code...i got a lot of it ;)
and sorry for bad english, am not that good as I would like to be...

Comment: Is there a way you could attach a screenshot of your GUI? Others might understand, but I'm having a particularly hard time picturing your GUI in my head.

Comment: sry for the title...but i cant post an image, i need 10 repurtations to do that...here is the description: in the left corner is a treeView called tView, and in the right corner is the imagePanel called imagePanel1 and there r a change button for the background, and an exit button, thats all

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, like this:

```
panel1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseUp);
```

just write panel1.anyEventUWant += and 2 times tab button....
it generate automaticly a new function with a single code line in it

here is an example

```
void panel1_MouseUp (object sender, EventArgs e)                  
{         
    //throw new NotImplementedException();     
}
```

U can access the panel like this: ((object)sender).